# How to set environmental in for by using os.Getenv()

Tags: golang

Does anyone know how to set the environmental variable in Golang by using :

```
os.Getenv()
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't use `os.Getenv` to set a variable but to get a value of the
variable. Use `os.Setenv` to set a variable like that:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "os"
)

func main() {
        os.Setenv("VAR", "10")
        fmt.Println("value of VAR:", os.Getenv("VAR"))
}
```

Also notice that retrieving value of  an environment variable that has been set in the same program doesn't make sense - they are usually used to pass environment to child processes.

Comment: Thanks for the information and my dout clearing... It realy help me....

Comment: If you like this answer please mark it as solved to let other users
know your problem is solved. Also see [What should I do when someone
answers my
question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)